# Debug help to do simple extracting via Xpath for Scrapy

Tags: debugging, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract the company name , company address and company number from this html

```
<div class="companyInformation">
                                    <p class="contentTitle">
                                        <a itemprop="CompanyName" href='/companies/toshio-s-pte-ltd/'>
                                            Toshio (S) Pte Ltd
                                        </a>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="data_BasicListings$ctl05$hidBasicComNo" id="data_BasicListings_ctl05_hidBasicComNo" value="T591107709" />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="address" itemprop="CompanyAddress">

                                        629 Aljunied Rd #08-13 Cititech Ind Bldg S(389838)
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="spriteBtn">
                                        <div class="greyBg">
                                            <span style="display: ">
                                                <a class="phoneBtn" title='+65  67431383#toshio-s-pte-ltd'
                                                    href="#"><span class="phoneLabel">CALL NOW</span> <span class="phoneNum">
                                                        +65  67431383
                                                    </span></a></span><span itemprop="Email" style="display: none">
                                                        <a href='/companies/toshio-s-pte-ltd/#enquiryForm'
                                                            class="enquireBtn"></a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <span itemprop="Website" style="display: none">
                                            <a rel="nofollow" href='/companies/toshio-s-pte-ltd/'
                                                class="websiteBtn">Home Page</a></span> <span><a class="locationBtn" id='vmap_bs_5'
                                                    target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Search_Results_Google_Map_Click','click','toshio-s-pte-ltd'])">
                                                    View Map</a></span>
                                    </div>
</div>
```

I arrive at this node by writing this xpath expression :

```
 hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
 names = hxs.select("//div[@class='companyInformation']")
```

I then attempt to extract the company name by

```
item["name"]=names.select("a/@itemprop='CompanyName'").extract()
```

This is my entire code

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from greenbook.items import GreenbookItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "greenbook"
    #allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.thegreenbook.com/products/absorbers-grease-oil/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        names = hxs.select("//div[@class='companyInformation']")
        items=[]
        for names in names:
            item = GreenbookItem()
            item["name"]=names.select("a/@itemprop='CompanyName'").extract()

        items.append(item)
        return item
```

I am currently extracting nothing , can someone help me out ?? I need to extract the Company Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't be able to check in more depth until later, but I noticed two issues with your parse function. First is that your loop set up is wrong, and also you need to return `items` rather than `item`.

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    names = hxs.select("//div[@class='companyInformation']")
    items = []
    for name in names:
        item = GreenbookItem()
        companyName = name.select(".//a[@itemprop='CompanyName']/text()").extract()[0]
        item["name"] = companyName.strip()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

I've edited the XPath to retrieve just the text of the company name, with the whitespace removed.

Comment: the result appears in the item list correctly on command prompt but it doesnt appear in the csv file

Comment: What command are you running to export results to a CSV file?

Comment: scrapy crawl greenbook -o items.csv -t csv

Comment: Works fine for me. Note that scrapy will create the file (which is then openable) in advance of writing output to it and at this point it will be empty. Have you tried reopening the file after the spider has finished crawling?

Comment: Thanks so much , i am wondering why do we need to put a [0] in front of extract() , what does it mean ??

Comment: Because .extract() returns a list. Admittedly a list with only one element in it, but a list nonetheless. Thus, to perform any kind of string operation such as strip() to remove whitespace, we have to specify that we only want the first element of the list which is indicated by [0].

Answer (score 0):

The second xpath `a/@itemprop='CompanyName'` should be changed to `.//a[@itemprop='CompanyName']`.

Also your for doed not look right to me . Try (not tested):

```
 for name in names:
            item = GreenbookItem()
            item["name"]=name.select(".//a[@itemprop='CompanyName']").extract()
```